# How do I return both values if the maximum if two rows are equal?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to find the persons with the maximum salaries in each department. I've got the code and found out the persons with the maximum salaries for each department. But then, when I looked at my data, there is another person that has the equal max value in the same department. Is there a way to return both persons' name?

example table:

```
Department  Salary  Name
Admin       $1000   Amy  
Admin       $900    Ben 
HR          $1500   Cassy
HR          $1500   Dan
```

I have tried this code:

```
SELECT department, Max(salary), name
FROM table
GROUP BY department
ORDER BY salary desc;
```

I've been getting Admin's person's details OK. But HR I can only get Cassy's name. Is there a way to get Dan's name in my output as well? Can anyone give me an example? Thank you

Comment: Your query is using `GROUP BY` in an invalid way. Any self-respecting database will reject that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm quite new to SQL. I use SQLite

Answer (score 3):

Hope this can help

```
SELECT department, salary, name
FROM table t
where salary= (select max(salary) from table where t.department = department)
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention the DBMS you are using.

With standard SQL, you can use window functions for this (which are supported by all modern DBMS):

```
select department, salary, name
from (
   select department, salary, name,
          dense_rank() over (partition by department order by salary desc) as rnk
   from department
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT department, salary, name
FROM tablename t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tablename
  WHERE department = t.department and salary > t.salary
)
ORDER BY salary desc, name;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q76fGXBKRKMX3ikyBsP5vU/1).
Results:

```
| Department | Salary | Name  |
| ---------- | ------ | ----- |
| HR         | 1500   | Cassy |
| HR         | 1500   | Dan   |
| Admin      | 1000   | Amy   |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation if you want one row per department with the names lists on the row:

```
select dept, salary, names
from (select dept, salary, group_concat(name) as names,
             row_number() over (partition by dept order by salary desc) as seqnum
      from example
      group by dept, salary
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```